# Laravel controller encoded with ioncube trigger segfault error

Tags: php, laravel, ioncube

I have laravel application with code encoded by ioncube 13 php 8.1 :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request) {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

In syslog I see segfault error:

```
localhost kernel: [167784.697796] php-fpm8.1[47572]: segfault at b343 ip 000055c3e7daa67c sp 00007ffe99912178 error 4 in php-fpm8.1[55c3e7cc8000+310000] likely on CPU 1 (core 0, socket 0)
```

with php 8.2 the same result

If I change code to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
     public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

it works

Why param `Request $request` trigger error ?
Do somebody faced this problem with ioncube and how sole it?

With php 7.4 I did not see this problem, only with ioncube with php8+

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the problem was solved with this solution.

You can do this to solve this problem in **laravel 9, php 8.1 and ioncube 13**

Encrypt these folders togeter:
**app
config
route
vendor**

**Put all of them in one folder and encrypt it at once.**

Because there are many vendor files, it slows down the speed when everything is encrypted, you can encrypt only the Laravel folder from within the vendor.

**or just encrypt only the laravel folder from vendor folder**

**app,
config,
route,
laravel**

Comment: Thank you. Encryption of vendor/vendor folder solved the problem